# Show that $e \cdot \ln x<x$ for all $x>0$

Tags: calculus

For some reason my calculation says $e\cdot\ln{x}>x$ when it is between $0$ and $1$. Can someone explain how to solve this question?

I did

$$\frac{e}{\ln{x}}-x < 0$$

Then i took derivative to see it's increase/decrease

$$ex-1< 0$$

$$ex<1$$

The last statement obviously has an error as $e=2.78$

Comment: Can you show your calculation?

Comment: At x = e inequality fails. We have an equality

Comment: Please format the question better, this hurts to read

Comment: The derivative being smaller than $0$ tells you absolutely nothing about the function being smaller than $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $0<x<1$, you have $\ln x <0$, so $e\ln x < 0$, and since $x>0$, it is clear that $e\ln x < 0$ so your calculation must have a mistake somewhere. In fact, your mistake is that when you took the derivative, you looked for the regions where the **derivative** of a function is smaller than $0$, but that doesn't tell you that the **function** is smaller than $0$. For example, the derivative of $f(x)=x^2$ is $2x$ and it is smaller than $0$ on $(-\infty, 0)$, however the **function** $x^2$ is positive on that region!

The derivative being negative simply tells you that the function is decreasing at a given point and gives you no information about the sign of the function (since you can always add a constant to a function and not change its derivative).

---

Also, the inequality you wrote is *not* true, since for $x=e$, you have $$e\cdot \ln e = e \not<e$$

---

But what is true is that $e\ln x \leq x$ for all $x>0$. You can show this by defining

$$f(x)=x-e\ln x$$

and then finding the minimum of $f$ on $(0,\infty)$ using derivatives. The derivative has only one zero and is negative left of it and positive right of it, so the zero must be at a minimum.

Comment: The function $f(x) = x - e\ln x$ is not defined at $x = 0$, so we want the minimum on $(0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Would like to rephrase a bit:

$e\ln x \le x$ for $x>0.$

1) $x \in (0,1):$  $\ln (x)<0.$

2) $x \ge 1.$

Consider as suggested :

$f(x) = x- e\ln(x).$

$f(1) = 1; $

$f'(x) = 1- e/x. $

At $x=e$ :

$f'(e) =0$, and  $f(e) = e-1> 0.$

$f''(x) = e/x^2 >0.$

The curve is convex and has

only one minimum at $x=e.$

Note :

$f'' >0$ implies $f'$  strictly increasing.

For $x> e:$

$f'(x) >0,$  hence $f(x)$ strictly increasing .